# AngularJS Id, Counter and List Iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qliksense

I'm working on a dynamic way to display Qlik objects on a page using JSON, JS and AngularJS. The strategy is to create a function 
$scope.showObject(myObject) that allows me to use qliks **app.vizualization.create** function to create the object at the specified ID. I'd call the function on the DOM side using ng-repeat to iterate on a list of objects that I need to diplay. The problem is that I'm pretty new with AngularJS and I encounterd this watch that calls the same function 10 times. At the same time I'm trying to bind an ID created with the help of the counter and bound with ng-attr-id="{{objectId}}".

Inside my controller:

```
var count = 1;
     $scope.showObjectsFrom = function(ourObject) {

     //creating my ID 
     var qvObject = "QV";
     $scope.objectId = qvObject + count.toString();

     //creating the object at the current ID
     app.visualization.create('kpi', [],
     JSON.stringify(ourObject)).then(function(vis) {
     vis.show(qvObject + count.toString())
         });

    count++;
    };
```

On the Dom side:

```
        <ul>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default-border border">
            <li ng-repeat="qlikObject in qlikAngularRepeatListe" 
class="qvobject" ng-attr-id="{{objectId}}">
{{showObjectsFrom(qlikObject)}}
</li>
            </div>
            </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? What can be changed I need to get rid of that watch that calls the function so many times but how?

Please Help!

Comment: When you change any property, The method will fire. It the behavior of angularjs. set the watch to your controller.

Comment: @Shohel how can this be done..i mean setting the watch on my controller?

Answer (score 0):

there is property in ng-repeat that called $index, it will return you the index of the item that runs in the current iteration.

you can try to create the id by doing this option:

```
ng-attr-id={{QV$index}}
```

or create a function that will get the index and returns back the string you need attaching to the current index.